# Initialization Error on running file in selenium cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

3 different files details is given below-Feature file/runner file and Step Def file

```
@featureTest Feature: Test Facbook smoke Scenario

   @Scenario1   Scenario: Test Login with valid Credentials
     Given Open chrome and start application
     When I enter valid username and valid password
     Then User should be login sucessfully
```

---

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="Features")
public class testrunner {

}


package stepdef;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class smoketest {

    WebDriver driver;
    @Given("^Open chrome and start application$")
    public void Open_chrome_and_start_application() throws Throwable{
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    }
    @When("^I enter valid username and valid password$")
public void I_enter_valid_username_and_valid_password() throws Throwable{

    }
    @Then("^User should be login sucessfully$")
public void User_should_be_login_sucessfully() throws Throwable{

    }

}
```

Comment: Can u add the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

please check feature file path. try with absolute path to the feature file and it is case sensitive. So check the feature file name for the same. For example if you keep the feature files under the Features folder of your project.

Try the following code.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="classpath:Features")
public class testrunner {

}
```

and your are setting glue path for step definitions. you will get step definition not found error even though you resolve the above error. unless or until you keep the class in the project directory.